# Print the names of all assets in the Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to debug why some assets are found and others not in the Asset Pipeline. i've tried a lot of obvious things (like typos, clearing tmp, clean/clobber).

Now I placed `binding.pry` right before where the image path is generated, and I'd like to view (print to the rails console / debugger) the name of every asset rails thinks is available.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the manifest:

```rb
# this is precompiled assets (?), however i had other assets show up here as well
Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets
```

Loop through asset paths:

```rb
Rails.configuration.assets.paths.flat_map{ |path| Dir.glob("#{path}/*.{js,css}") }
```

This will show pretty much all the available information from *sprockets*:

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application.js").to_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, this doesn't answer the question (how to view the available assets *in the console/debugger*), and therefore shall not be accepted as an answer, but it's a small start: showing how to view assets from the terminal:

```
rails webpacker:clean
rails webpacker:clobber
rails webpacker:compile
```

The last step will print all the available assets to the terminal.

Another way is to run `bin/webpack` from the terminal, and in the output will be each asset. Again, this doesn't provide the list from the *console or debugger*.